# What is the difference between OpenERP and Odoo?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8

What all are the difference between OpenERP and Odoo.
I know Odoo(v8) is lastest version of OpenERP(v7)
and also explain something about Odoo V9. Here difference in the sense it means what are all the additional feature available in Odoo and also about extra feature included in Odoo v9.

Comment: You can take a look at the novelties for the users here: https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/blog/odoo-news-5/post/odoo-8-is-here-181. About programming, a new API has been implemented so now you can work with it in an easier way (but you can still use old API).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In OpenERP V7:**

There have no any kind of website interface and E commerce faciality in this version so that the new territory comes in the market and new revolution for new API and also added new modules for Odoo 8.0

**OpenERP V7 To Odoo 8.0**

https://www.odoo.com/blog/odoo-news-5/post/odoo-8-release-notes-186

**New Features for Odoo 8.0**

http://www.nevprobusinesssolutions.com/top-12-odoo-8-features/

http://pragtechblog.blogspot.in/2014/04/openerp-8-features.html

**For Odoo 9.0**

**By Febian Pianker**

https://www.odoo.com/slides/slide/keynote-odoo-9-new-features-201

**By netjunky**

http://netjunky.net/odoo-9-new-features/

You can check for the above reference links to understand the   OpenERP 7.0 To Odoo 8.0 To Odoo 9.0

I hope my answer may help you :)

Answer (score 2):

You have the [Release Notes](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/blog/odoo-news-5/post/odoo-8-release-notes-186) of Odoo v8 in the oficial website with all the changes. And you can see what's new in these [Odoo v9 videos](https://www.youtube.com/user/OpenERPonline/videos)

Answer (score 1):

before the odoo v8 the product were named openerp "as it was fully open source"

they've introduced a brand new ORM API for their framework and they introduce the web client and so on, then they rename the product to it's current name "Odoo" and every year or so they introduce an new version of it.
one major change happened after version 10 they toke off the accounting module and the community version left off with invoicing system.